# Solspace importer how to tell it which channel to import to?

Tags: solspace, solspace-importer

I'm trying to set up an import profile with with [Solspace Importer](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/importer/) to upload CSV files with channel entries but I don't see any way of telling it which channel I want to import to.

Am I missing something fundamental here?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [documentation](http://www.solspace.com/docs/importer/control_panel/), the channel should appear as the first field in the create new import profile screen.

Comment: Thanks, it's just not that clear from the documentation that you have to upload a file before getting to the screen with the option to select the actual channel.